# What is MonoProcessor in Spring reactive used for?

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-reactive

While looking at the source code of the `WiretapConnector` from Spring framework I stumbled upon an object of type `MonoProcessor`. I tried Googling explanations of uses for it but to no avail.

Javadoc doesn't say much to a Reactive/Reactor layperson:

> A `MonoProcessor` is a Mono extension that implements stateful
>   semantics. Multi-subscribe is allowed. Once a `MonoProcessor` has been
>   resolved, newer subscribers will benefit from the cached result.

This last sentence hints that the result of calculation is cached and it seems this to be the use of `MonoProcessor` in this [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WiretapConnector.java#L139).

Could someone clarify what would be the intended use-case of `MonoProcessor` and why was it introduced in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case is you want a processor that creates a "hot" Mono, not a Flux. Also provides processor functions such as cancel, dispose, onNext etc. Since Mono is a single value, it in turn can only consume a single onNext and as such the result is cached for any future subscriptions. Effectively turning it from a "hot" to "cold".

Example of hot Mono

```
   //Set up flux processor, sink for thread safety
    DirectProcessor<Integer> directProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();
    FluxSink<Integer> sink = directProcessor.serialize().sink();

    //Allows dynamic creation of Mono value, after initialisation
    MonoProcessor<Integer> processor =
            directProcessor.filter(s -> s > 5)
            .next()
            .toProcessor();

     //Set up subscriptions, no values have been submitted to either yet
     processor.map(i -> "monoProc: " + i).subscribe(System.out::println);
     directProcessor.map(i -> "DirectProc: " + i).subscribe(System.out::println);

    //Uncomment and above Mono subscription will never occur
    //processor.cancel();

    //Values from some other service or whatever
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sink.next(i);
    }

    //Do something later with cached result
    processor.map(i -> "monoProc cached: " + i).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: When would you use `toProcessor` over `cache`. From what I can tell, both of these provide a cached mono result. One thing I can see is the `MonoProcessor` subscription can be cancelled - is this the only thing?